# How can I get my webcam to work in ICANHAZCHAT?

Tags: webcam

I can cam up in cheese and skype, but can't in ICANHAZCHAT. I can even see the other cams. What do I do? I have a gateway laptop (basically acer) with a suyin 1.3mp.

Answer (score 1):

Check out their very detailed help page http://www.icanhazchat.com/CamHelp.

Comment: That requires wine and many cam. I can't even get to the configure part once the cam is broadcasting.

Comment: All it requires is Adobe Flash and a webcam, but not wine. If you don't have flash installed, you can't use that chat.